# Proof that an isometry preserves straight lines

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification

I have been trying to understand how to prove the corollary of this theorem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvp8g.png), for the theorem I basically prove from a point $X$ on segment $PQ$ that $F(X)$ lies on segment $F(P) F(Q)$ from the fact that isometries are distance preserving, then segment $PQ$ is contained in segment $F(P) F(Q)$. How could the same be shown for a line thus proving the corollary too?

Comment: Call me naive, but if straight lines are paths of shortest distance, and isometries preserve distance...

Comment: Use RAA and the result for segments.

Comment: If lengths are preserved then any multiple or fraction of distance between mapped  points.are preserved. Associated betweenness, angles, geodesic curvature etc. of first fundamental form are all held invariant.